# Ants on corn - urgent pest?

Tags: ants, sweetcorn

I have ants on my corn.  They are either depositing or collecting something.  What are they doing and how can I kill them safely?  Are they harming the ears?

[image: ant activity on a corn stalk]

[image: under the uppermost leaf]

Comment: Those are not ants. Some type of beetle. There is an ant in the second picture. Where in the world is this?

Comment: Maybe 2 ants, and a lot of these beetles, which are smaller than the ants, so they MIGHT be these guys? https://extension.entm.purdue.edu/fieldcropsipm/insects/corn-flea-beetle.php

Answer (score 2):

The ants aren't the problem—the aphids that they're "milking" for honeydew are. The first picture shows a very large group of aphids nestling in the stalk; the second shows several ants among a smaller group of aphids. Note the "horns" on the rear-ends of the insects; this marks them as aphids.

The safest way to kill the aphids is via insecticidal soap, which can be as simple as a vegetable-based soap (like castille soap) in a water solution. Clemson University has an excellent [fact sheet](https://hgic.clemson.edu/factsheet/insecticidal-soaps-for-garden-pest-control/) on the science behind using insecticidal soap and instructions for use. Note that this sheet recommends using a commercial product over a home-made one, due to the possibility of damage to the plant.

[This site](https://soilseedandgarden.com/how-to-make-your-own-homemade-insecticidal-soap/) discusses the pros and cons of both commercial and homemade soaps Note that it, too, states that homemade soaps can damage the plant treated with them:

> Too much soap concentration compared to water will give you a more potent bug killer. But, it can also damage the leaves of the plant which solves one problem but creates a new problem.

The author then specifically recommends using castille soap and includes it in a recipe for homemade insecticidal soap.

Your other alternative is ladybug larvae, but you'll either need to be patient (they WILL find the aphids, eventually) or order some to be send to your house.